# Click Actions works on second click

Tags: javascript, jquery

This code works properly on first click. When repeated its works only on second click on same element.
**HTML**

```
<div id="monthly-table">
<a href="#" class="monthly active">Monthly</a>
<a href="#" onclick="subscriptionTable(this)" class="yearly">Yearly</a>
<h1>Monthly</h1></div><div id="yearly-table" style="display:none">
<a href="#" onclick="subscriptionTable(this)" class="monthly">Monthly</a>
<a href="#" class="yearly active">Yearly</a>
<h1>Yearly</h1></div>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
function subscriptionTable(el) {
   $(el).on('click', function() {
       if ($('#yearly-table').is(':hidden')) {
          $('#yearly-table').show();
          $('#monthly-table').hide();
        } else {
         $('#yearly-table').hide();
         $('#monthly-table').show();
       }
      return false;
   });
};
```

Comment: why not like this http://http://jsfiddle.net/eLj3v64g/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the inline click handler to register the jQuery click handler, use jQuery dom ready handler to register the click handler

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $('.period').on('click', function() {
    var $target = $($(this).attr('href')).show();
    $('.target').not($target).hide();
    return false;
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="monthly-table" class="target">
  <a href="#" class="monthly active">Monthly</a>
  <a href="#yearly-table" class="yearly period">Yearly</a>
  <h1>Monthly</h1>
</div>
<div id="yearly-table" class="target" style="display:none">
  <a href="#monthly-table" class="monthly period">Monthly</a>
  <a href="#" class="yearly active">Yearly</a>
  <h1>Yearly</h1>
</div>
```